# Android View Clipping

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, clip

Is there any way to define the clip region of a ViewGroup in android (Honeycomb)? For example, I have a ListView with an image background that has rounded corners. As I scroll through the list, the children stick out past the corners of the background - I would prefer them to clip within the rounded corners.
[image: Left: unclipped, Right: clipped]

The left image is what it is currently doing, and the right is what I'd like.

I was looking at ClipDrawable, but it seems that this may only be used for progress bars?

Also, I'm trying to do this in a widget. So I cannot use a custom view and override onDraw for masking.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I am also trying to make this happen in a widget.

Answer (score 31):

Make sure `layout` has a background with rounded corners.

*Kotlin*

```
layout.outlineProvider = ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND
layout.clipToOutline = true
```

*Java*

```
layout.setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND);
layout.setClipToOutline(true);
```

Comment: Note: Requires API Level 21

Answer (score 26):

Try subclassing ViewGroup and overriding the OnDraw method as follows, substituting in values for RADIUS_IN_PIXELS:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path clipPath = new Path();
    clipPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(canvas.getClipBounds()), RADIUS_IN_PIXELS, RADIUS_IN_PIXELS, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

...and also create a custom drawable like this called something like 'rounded', substituting in YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR and RADIUS_IN_DP, making sure to match the rounding of the rectangle in DP to your previous clipping radius in PX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="RADIUS_IN_DP" />
    <solid android:color="YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR"/>
</shape>
```

Then you can use that subclass in your layout, adding the lines

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded"
android:clipChildren="true"
```

All children will clip to the bounds you specify in the OnDraw() override, and a background will be added based on your 'rounded' drawable.

Comment: NEVER instantiate objects inside `onDraw`, it'll lead to lags.

Comment: the original question is asking for something that works with RemoteViews.

Answer (score 6):

Create custom layout with `overridden onDraw(Canvas canvas)`

call `canvas.clipRect(0, 0, mCanvasWidth, mCanvasHeight);`

this will clip all views that goes out of layout boundary.

And don't forget to call `setWillNotDraw(false)` in constructor, so your onDraw will execute

Answer (score 1):

How about this: [How to render an Android view to a bitmap](http://code.neenbedankt.com/how-to-render-an-android-view-to-a-bitmap), then clip that bitmap.

Or, another idea, use `FrameLayout`, stack your clip mask on top of your ViewGroup. Clip mask would have transparent middle, opaque borders.

In both cases, I guess it will be tricky to handle user input...

Comment: The first option wouldn't work, because it is in a widget, thus it must only use RemoteViews compatible Views.

Comment: And for the second option, since it's a home screen widget, a clip mask would not be viable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Path p = new Path()

// define your clipping path...

canvas.clipPath(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look to [WhatsUp](https://lh6.ggpht.com/ekvKaO9HD6MxRANllZKgXmtlpLyloJFpRRNiZeyrYPFGzpOfLWjn8BSZd2c) you can see that in the contact picture there is an image rounded by a rounded border.
To do this I have put the ImageView inside a FrameLayout (FrameLayout because I use ProgressBar in front of picture to notify loading [actually invisible]) that has rounded border. The picture has a square shape but to refine it, you need to work with canvas.

Take another look at this [link](http://ruibm.com/?p=184) that will solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

To add onto the answer by @Marco, you can also provide a custom `View.outlineProvider`. I ran into a similar issue using Google's newer `MaterialCardView`. For some reason, that view does not clip its children with the rounded corners. Child views would just draw on top of the rounded corner.

Kotlin:

```
val cornerRadius = 16.dp()
materialCardView.apply {
    clipToOutline = true
    outlineProvider = object : ViewOutlineProvider() {
        override fun getOutline(view: View?, outline: Outline?) {
            view?.apply {
                outline?.setRoundRect(0, 0, width, (height + cornerRadius).toInt(), cornerRadius)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you can used the Canvas.clipRegion method to clip the differences of the to views.

Answer (score -4):

Give android:clipToPadding a try. It will solve your problem.