# How to make a view with rounded corners?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-view, android-shape

I am trying to make a view in android with rounded edges. The solution I found so far is to define a shape with rounded corners and use it as the background of that view.

Here is what I did, define a drawable as given below:

```
<padding
android:top="2dp"
android:bottom="2dp"/>
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
```

Now I used this as the background for my layout as below:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner">
```

This works perfectly fine, I can see that the view has rounded edges.

But my layout has got many other child views in it, say an ImageView or a `MapView`. When I place an `ImageView` inside the above layout, the corners of image are not clipped/cropped, instead it appears full.

I have seen other workarounds to make it work like the one explained [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-round-corners-on-an-android-imageview-with-this-hack/).

> But is there a method to set rounded corners for a view and all its
>   child views are contained within that main view that has rounded
>   corners?

Comment: What if you use a Custom layout extending to LinearLayout, and while its object is created, iterate all children of that Layout and apply rounded border background to them?

Comment: android.support.v7.widget.CardView seem to be the solution for this

Comment: This solution solved it for me, but requires subclassing: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574212/android-view-clipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574212/android-view-clipping)

Comment: Google have new framework,
new technologies is better 

[Jetpack Compose][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round/64087445#64087445

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Another approach is to make a custom layout class like the one below. This layout first draws its contents to an offscreen bitmap, masks the offscreen bitmap with a rounded rect and then draws the offscreen bitmap on the actual canvas.

I tried it and it seems to work (at least for my simple testcase). It will of course affect performance compared to a regular layout.

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class RoundedCornerLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private final static float CORNER_RADIUS = 40.0f;

    private Bitmap maskBitmap;
    private Paint paint, maskPaint;
    private float cornerRadius;

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap offscreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas offscreenCanvas = new Canvas(offscreenBitmap);

        super.draw(offscreenCanvas);

        if (maskBitmap == null) {
            maskBitmap = createMask(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        }

        offscreenCanvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0f, 0f, maskPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(offscreenBitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);
    }

    private Bitmap createMask(int width, int height) {
        Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mask);

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, width, height), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);

        return mask;
    }
}
```

Use this like a normal layout:

```
<com.example.RoundedCornerLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/test"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        />

</com.example.RoundedCornerLayout>
```

Comment: I am use this layout for imageview with zoom function inside, but this layout cant detect touch listener when i try to zoom, how to add touch listener function in this layout?

Comment: This works however maps will not render to it.  Any known fix for that?

Comment: I used this method and works fine. But when I put an EditText inside the layout, the screen does not  update when I type in. When I close the  window, the text comes into display. The screen is getting updated once I close the keyboard. Any fix to this?

Comment: Only problem with this when you use it with Recycler view is that its not waiting for complete set of items to be loaded. And rounds just a few items. Is there a reason for this to happen?

Comment: @SajibAcharya have you been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: This doesnt work with images loaded from glide library that use placeholder transitions (Or any other animated children actually). I have an alternate solution but it requires your background color to be a solid color. See https://gist.github.com/grennis/da9f86870c45f3b8ae00912edb72e868

Comment: Only left top corner is rounded

Comment: If you are trying to use this view with an `android:elevation` attribute it can render the shadow incorrectly. To correct this, see [this gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/ed-george/b94990d6c70df339b5799d1d4be982bf)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Also one can change the class to inherit from any other layout as well, e.g. RelativeLayout.

Comment: @user1758835 same is happening with me. Did you find anything?

Comment: How can I add border to this CustomView?

Comment: I was searching for two days for right answer. Here, I found it...Thanks a ton!!!!

Comment: creating a new bitmap in draw() is not a good idea. see @Sushant 's answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074784/how-to-make-a-view-in-android-with-rounded-corners/35266854#35266854

Comment: Fine and useful solution but too expensive. RecyclerView with just six elements which contains one picture can't scroll smoothly. And it's not depending on device power (Samsung S9 or Wileyfox Swift 2).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41098690/4399323 is better answer!

Comment: Is it possible to round only the top left and right corner? The bottom corners can be square and unchanged.

Comment: I get way too many compile warnings for this to be a viable solution

Answer (score 111):

Or you can use a `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <!--YOUR CONTENT-->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I've tried so many ways, yours is the best solution to my problem. THANKS!

Comment: Not able to remove the elevation. Works fine if the design requires elevation.

Comment: @AbdalrahmanShatou https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html there are properties for that. Have you try setting them to "0" ?

Comment: One drawback is that it doesn't support <21 android api's

Comment: Works perfectly for API => 27, I used MaterialCardView with app:cardCornerRadius, app:strokeColor, app:strokeWidth and app:cardElevation = 0dp

Answer (score 70):

shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#f6eef1" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

and inside you layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shape">

        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:src="@drawable/your image"
             android:background="@drawable/shape">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Zach: In what way did it fail to work? The same as how your app was working when you asked the original question?

Comment: clipChildren is useless and the image view still extends outside the view.

Comment: I wish I could give you a bounty for that. Thank you

Comment: I don't think this approach would work if the image is a rectangular one, as the background will be drawn behind the content of the image. This might only work with images that have transparency and themselves have rounded corners.

Answer (score 29):

[Jaap van Hengstum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074784/how-to-make-a-view-in-android-with-rounded-corners#answer-26201117) works great however I think it is expensive and if we apply this method on a Button for example, the touch effect is lost since the view is rendered as a bitmap.

For me the best method and the simplest one consists in applying a mask on the view, like that:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight);

    float cornerRadius = <whatever_you_want>;
    this.path = new Path();
    this.path.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, width, height), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (this.path != null) {
        canvas.clipPath(this.path);
    }
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: How to use this?

Comment: @MaksimKniazev Make a subclass of the layout you want (for instance: FrameLayout), then paste these two methods into this subclass and replace '<whatever_you_want>' with your desired corner radius value (from resources for example). That's it. Is it enough clear for you or do you need an example?

Comment: Thank you so much, it really works better for RecyclerView!

Comment: Can you give an example? Does not seem to work on me.

Answer (score 25):

In case you want to round some specific corner.

```
fun setCorners() {
        
        val mOutlineProvider = object : ViewOutlineProvider() {
            override fun getOutline(view: View, outline: Outline) {

                val left = 0
                val top = 0;
                val right = view.width
                val bottom = view.height
                val cornerRadiusDP = 16f
                val cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, cornerRadiusDP, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()

                // all corners
                outline.setRoundRect(left, top, right, bottom, cornerRadius.toFloat())

                /* top corners
                outline.setRoundRect(left, top, right, bottom+cornerRadius, cornerRadius.toFloat())*/

                /* bottom corners
                outline.setRoundRect(left, top - cornerRadius, right, bottom, cornerRadius.toFloat())*/

                /* left corners
                outline.setRoundRect(left, top, right + cornerRadius, bottom, cornerRadius.toFloat())*/

                /* right corners
                outline.setRoundRect(left - cornerRadius, top, right, bottom, cornerRadius.toFloat())*/

                /* top left corner
                outline.setRoundRect(left , top, right+ cornerRadius, bottom + cornerRadius, cornerRadius.toFloat())*/

                /* top right corner
                outline.setRoundRect(left - cornerRadius , top, right, bottom + cornerRadius, cornerRadius.toFloat())*/

                /* bottom left corner
                outline.setRoundRect(left, top - cornerRadius, right + cornerRadius, bottom, cornerRadius.toFloat())*/

                /* bottom right corner
                outline.setRoundRect(left - cornerRadius, top - cornerRadius, right, bottom, cornerRadius.toFloat())*/

            }
        }

        myView.apply {
            outlineProvider = mOutlineProvider
            clipToOutline = true
        }
    }
```

Can be used on a LinearLayout with children that looks like this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: Good Answer! Worked perfectly for a layout that had several views inside and I wanted to round the outside box.

Comment: it should definitely be the accepted answer

Comment: Where is this written? Inside a custom view object?

Answer (score 23):

Create a xml file called `round.xml` in the `drawable` folder and paste this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
  <stroke android:width=".05dp" android:color="#d2d2d2" />
  <corners android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

then use the `round.xml` as `background` to any item. Then it will give you rounded corners.

Answer (score 19):

If you are having problem while adding touch listeners to the layout. Use this layout as parent layout.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class RoundedCornerLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private final static float CORNER_RADIUS = 6.0f;
    private float cornerRadius;

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }


    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int count = canvas.save();

        final Path path = new Path();
        path.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.REPLACE);

        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(count);
    }


}
```

as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.view.RoundedCornerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/patentItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">
        ... your child goes here
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.example.view.RoundedCornerLayout>
```

Comment: It works well if there are not many animation on screen, which make screen draw again and again many times; since, it will slow performance critically. Should try cardview, which has an efficient round corner method (not use clipping path or canvas.drawRoundRect - bad in below API 17, but use porterFilterDuffColor)

Answer (score 17):

With the Material Components Library the best way to make a `View` with rounded corners is to use the **`MaterialShapeDrawable`**.

Create a ShapeAppearanceModel with custom rounded corners:

```
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModelLL1 = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius16)
        .build();
```

Create a `MaterialShapeDrawable`:

```
MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawableLL1 = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModeLL1);
```

If you want to apply also an elevationOverlay for the dark theme use this:

```
MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawableLL1 = MaterialShapeDrawable.createWithElevationOverlay(this, 4.0f);
shapeDrawableLL1.setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeAppearanceModelLL1);
```

Optional: apply to the shapeDrawable a background color and a stroke

```
shapeDrawableLL1.setFillColor(
       ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color...));
 shapeDrawableLL1.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
 shapeDrawableLL1.setStrokeColor(
       ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color...));
```

Finally apply the shapeDrawable as background in your `LinearLayout` (or other view):

```
LinearLayout linearLayout1= findViewById(R.id.ll_1);
ViewCompat.setBackground(linearLayout1,shapeDrawableLL1);
```

[image]

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. The easiest solution by far!

Answer (score 11):

In Android L you will be able to just use [View.setClipToOutline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClipToOutline(boolean)) to get that effect. In previous versions there is no way to just clip the contents of a random ViewGroup in a certain shape.

You will have to think of something that would give you a similar effect:

- If you only need rounded corners in the ImageView, you can use a shader to 'paint' the image over the shape you are using as background. Take a look at [this library](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView/) for an example.
- If you really need every children to be clipped, maybe you can another view over your layout? One with a background of whatever color you are using, and a round 'hole' in the middle? You could actually create a custom ViewGroup that draws that shape over every children overriding the onDraw method.

Comment: Thanks! Good job! I removed a gray rectangular selection below rounded `TextView` when clicked.

Answer (score 7):

The `CardView` worked for me in API 27 in Android Studio 3.0.1. The `colorPrimary` was referenced in the `res/values/colors.xml` file and is just an example. For the layout_width of `0dp` it will stretch to the width of the parent. You'll have to configure the constraints and width/height to your needs.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary">

    <!-- put your content here -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a xml file under your drawable folder with following code. (The name of the file I created is rounded_corner.xml)

### rounded_corner.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <!-- view background color -->
        <solid
            android:color="#a9c5ac" >
        </solid>

        <!-- view border color and width -->
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#1c1b20" >
        </stroke>

        <!-- If you want to add some padding -->
        <padding
            android:left="4dp"
            android:top="4dp"
            android:right="4dp"
            android:bottom="4dp"    >
        </padding>

        <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp"   >
        </corners>
    </shape>
```

And keep this `drawable` as `background` for the view to which you want to keep rounded corner border. Let’s keep it for a `LinearLayout`

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi, This layout has rounded corner borders ..."
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How about if i would change background color for the element, only the rounded corner is need not the background color, like we have to it for every element

Comment: @Zero0 If this answer does not answer your query then why are you down bote this. This may help many other devs. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` like so:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_4"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/dimen_4"
        app:contentPadding="@dimen/dimen_10">

       ...

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

OR

shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#f6eef1" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

and inside you layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape">

        ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

To create round corner image using com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01

```
 float radius = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_radius_hug);
    shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
            .toBuilder()
            .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
            .build();

imageView.setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeAppearanceModel)
```

or if you want to use it in xml file:

```
  <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumb"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circleImageView"
            />
```

in style.xml add this:

```
<style name="circleImageView" parent="">
      <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
      <item name="cornerSize">10%</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

follow this tutorial **and all the discussion beneath it** - 
http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

according to this post written by Guy Romain, one of the leading developers of the entire Android UI toolkit,  it is possible to make a container (and all his child views) with rounded corners, but he explained that it too expensive (from performances of rendering issues).

I'll recommend you to go according to his post, and if you want rounded corners, then implement rounded corners `ImageView` according to this post.   then, you could place it inside a container with any background, and you'll get the affect you wish.

that's what I did also also eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Difference from Jaap van Hengstum's answer:

1. Use *BitmapShader* instead of mask bitmap.
2. Create bitmap only once.

```java
public class RoundedFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private Bitmap mOffscreenBitmap;
    private Canvas mOffscreenCanvas;
    private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private RectF mRectF;

    public RoundedFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public RoundedFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public RoundedFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mOffscreenBitmap == null) {
            mOffscreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mOffscreenCanvas = new Canvas(mOffscreenBitmap);
            mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mOffscreenBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);
            mRectF = new RectF(0f, 0f, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        }
        super.draw(mOffscreenCanvas);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(mRectF, 8, 8, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class RoundedCornerLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private double mCornerRadius;

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    public double getCornerRadius() {
        return mCornerRadius;
    }

    public void setCornerRadius(double cornerRadius) {
        mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int count = canvas.save();

        final Path path = new Path();
        path.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()), (float) mCornerRadius, (float) mCornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.REPLACE);

        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial link you provided seems to suggest that you need to set the layout_width and layout_height properties, of your child elements to match_parent.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this property with your linear layout it will help
tools:context=".youractivity"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {

        Bitmap roundedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(roundedBitmap);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return roundedBitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen many solutions, but most of them are useless with Image
> View unless you change Image View to other design components, and I do
> not recommend them because they may not be compatible with some
> **
> solution using:

**
**Width and color of stroke in drawable
And Margin for the picture**

> versions. Here is the quick solution.
> **The first step:**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/a" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/card_helh" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

> design shape
>
> **The second step:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/_10dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

**

> A note
> ** about setting the night mode, set the color stroke color to the color of the container's night so that it appears more homogeneous This
> solution works 100%
> This solution is mine and I am currently using it