# Children of ListView doesn't respect parents border radius

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

This is what I want to obtain (note - the blue is only hilited):
[image]
A ListView with rounded corners and children of it with with white-lightgrey background of every n-th.

This is my preview in AS:
[image]

And I have this `MyArrayAdapter` to paint every 2nd row in different color:

```
public class AlternateRowArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    private int[] colors;

    public AlternateRowArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int layout,
                                    @IdRes int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<String> objects)
    {
        super(context, layout, textViewResourceId, objects);
        colors = new int[] {ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.getResources(), R.color.white, null) ,
                            ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.getResources(), R.color.lmsLightGrey, null)};
    }
    /**
     * Display rows in alternating colors
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Although the children of ListView doesnt respect the border radius of parent and put this background color to full rectangle of theirs:
[image]
How can I tell children to obey it's parent border radius?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26074784/1083957) is your case.

Comment: @azizbekian, can I easily extend ListView like in this post and apply overriden methods?

Comment: I think it will work.

Comment: It worked, but I have lost my preview in activity.xml, can it be restored when using custom views?

Comment: Also how can I make it vulnerable to my shape `<corners android:radius="8dp" />`? I don't want to be able to edit it only in .java file