# Android - Displaying ExoPlayer in a circle

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to display a ExoPlayerView inside a circle, overlaying another ExoPlayer (picture in picture):
[image]

I have tried putting the 2nd player inside a frame with rounded corners (both [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074784/how-to-make-a-view-in-android-with-rounded-corners)) but the player will always escape the parent frame and draw the video's full rectangle.

I found [this solution](https://medium.com/@fabrantes/rounded-video-corners-on-android-part-i-68eca391f39b) which uses a GLSurfaceView, however this solution uses the classic MediaPlayer and not ExoPlayer.

Comment: Have you tried using the solution you linked and using the GLSurfaceView just like you'd use a SurfaceView with ExoPlayer? (setting up the surface listener and passing the surface to ExoPlayer)

Comment: Anyone else running into this, the solution is to use TextureViews instead of SurfaceViews

Answer (score 1):

For the one that's supposed to have rounded corners, you can set in the layout XML file this about it:

```
app:surface_type="texture_view"
```

Found this solution [**here**](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2837).

The drawback of using this is mainly performance and battery usage (written [**here**](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/faqs.html)) :

> Should I use SurfaceView or TextureView? SurfaceView has a number of
>   benefits over TextureView for video playback:
>
> Significantly lower power consumption on many devices. More accurate
>   frame timing, resulting in smoother video playback. Support for secure
>   output when playing DRM protected content. SurfaceView should
>   therefore be preferred over TextureView where possible. TextureView
>   should be used only if SurfaceView does not meet your needs. One
>   example is where smooth animations or scrolling of the video surface
>   is required prior to Android N (see [How do I get smooth
>   animation/scrolling of video?](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/faqs.html#how-do-i-get-smooth-animationscrolling-of-video)). For this case, it’s preferable to use
>   TextureView only when [**SDK_INT**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) is less than 24 (Android N) and
>   SurfaceView otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom container for it. try this and put you player view in it.

```
public class RoundFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

private final Path clip = new Path();

private int posX;
private int posY;
private int radius;

public RoundFrameLayout(Context context) {
    this(context,null);

}

public RoundFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs,0);
}

public RoundFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    // We can use outlines on 21 and up for anti-aliased clipping.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        setClipToOutline(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
    posX = Math.round((float) width / 2);
    posY = Math.round((float) height / 2);

    // noinspection NumericCastThatLosesPrecision
    radius = (int) Math.floor((float) Math.min(width, height) / 2);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        setOutlineProvider(new OutlineProvider(posX, posY, radius));
    } else {
        clip.reset();
        clip.addCircle(posX, posY, radius, Direction.CW);
    }
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Not needed on 21 and up since we're clipping to the outline instead.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        canvas.clipPath(clip);
    }

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Don't pass touch events that occur outside of our clip to the children.
    float distanceX = Math.abs(event.getX() - posX);
    float distanceY = Math.abs(event.getY() - posY);
    double distance = Math.hypot(distanceX, distanceY);

    return distance > radius;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
static class OutlineProvider extends ViewOutlineProvider {

    final int left;
    final int top;
    final int right;
    final int bottom;

    OutlineProvider(int posX, int posY, int radius) {
        left = posX - radius;
        top = posY - radius;
        right = posX + radius;
        bottom = posY + radius;
    }

    @Override
    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        outline.setOval(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: As mentioned in the question, this solution does not work as the player does not respect the rounded corners of the parent frame.