# Create rounded corners on View

Tags: android, view, rounded-corners, cornerradius

Is there any way to create rounded corners of a `View` inside the `LinearLayout` instead of using `shape`?

```
<View
 android:layout_width="48dp"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:layout_height="48dp"
 android:background="#f55151" />
```

Comment: Have u tried to use `CardView`??

Comment: @NileshRathod No

Comment: You can use `CardView` or tried with and use `app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074784/how-to-make-a-view-in-android-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CardView and inside the cardview you can make your own views. On the CardView you can set the card_view:cardCornerRadius.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
   xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/yourColor"
   card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

   <View
      android:layout_width="48dp"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:background="#f55151" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don`t want to use shape CardView is the easiest way:
for more detail look at the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.htm)

first add this line to your dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

then use it like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can find more options [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#summary) like: corner radius, elevation, background color and so on.