# Strange rectangle shape appears in the middle of cardView if I set semi-transparent color to cardBackgroundColor

Tags: android, xml, cardview

I have the following layout.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#AACC0000"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Some text" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

If I set semi-transparent color `(#AACC0000)` to `cardBackgroundColor`, strange rectangle shape appears in the middle of cardView.

[image]

If I set color without alpha channel `(#CC0000)`, that rectangle shape dissapears. Regards

[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue, do you get the same on real device and emulator?

Comment: I get this issue on a real device. In the xml editor this issue is not shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of elevation . Set `cardElevation` to `0dp` and check

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#AACC0000"
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Some text" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But why it happens. What if I want use cardElevation in this case?

Comment: I am not sure if its possible with cardview , you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62263221/6478047

Answer (score 1):

Adding alpha value `android:alpha="0.99"` fixes the issue.
Took 0.99 as higher side alpha value

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:alpha="0.99"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#AACC0000"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Some text" />
```

[image]