# Android make view fill it's background shape

Tags: java, android, xml, android-xml

**Question:**

I have got an `Activity` used as a popup.

It's background is a shape with rounded corners.

But the items of it's content view don't *fill out* the shape. They are more likely *inside* of an invisible rectangle inside of the shape.

Can I somehow make them fill the shape and being *cut* when overlapping the corners?

---

**Solution:**

1. Add this code to the view with the shape background:

`view.setClipToOutline(true); --> clips the view view.setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND); --> tells the view to be clipped by the background(shape)`

2. If the paddings of the view are too big, just make them smaller so you can see an effect of the clipping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do this. It's called `View Clipping`.

Here is an existing question about clipping:
[Android View Clipping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5574212/6007104)

You have 2 options:

1- Implement a custom `View` and override `onDraw` so you can perform the clipping manually. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28206555/6007104

2- Use `View.outlineProvider` and `View.clipToOutline`. This is the easier option, but only available on SDK 21+. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54202660/6007104